# postman no me muestra los datos al "registrar" con nodejs

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

En postman me sale el siguiente "error", pero en la terminal que estoy utilizando, cygwin si muestra los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me dio con el código:

```
function saveUser(req, res){
var user = new User();

var params = req.body;

console.log(params);

user.name = params.name;
user.surname = params.surname;
user.email = params.email;
user.role = 'ROLE_USER';
user.image = 'null';

if(params.password){
    // Encriptar contraseña
    bcrypt.hash(params.password, null, null, function(err, hash){
        user.password = hash;

        if(user.name != null && user.surname != null && user.email != null){
            // Guardar el usuario
            user.save((err, userStored) => {
                if(err){
                    res.status(500).send({message: 'Error al guardar el usuario'});
                }else{
                    if(!userStored){
                        res.status(404).send({message: 'No se ha registrado el usuario'});
                    }else{
                        res.status(200).send({user: userStored});
                    }
                }
            });

        }else{
            res.status(200).send({message: 'Rellena todos los campos'});
        }
    });
}else{
    res.status(200).send({message: 'Introduce la contraseña'});
}

}
```

Ya tengo la conexión a la base de datos hecha con mongodb.
Mande llamar model user y bycript

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var User = require('../models/user');
```

Tambien estoy exportando la función saveUser:

```
module.exports = {
pruebas,
saveUser
};
```

pero aun así no me muestra nada y no encuentro como arreglarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a quien le llegue a pasar lo mismo, lo que hice fue desinstalar la versión de mongoose mas reciente y puse la 4.10.8

con cygwin el comando:

```
npm install mongoose@4.10.8 --save
```

Comment: Eso te sirvió para que te retorne el response en postam?

Comment: así es, con eso pude correr lo que buscaba